# Python Tornado not implemented error workaround

Tags: python, tornado

This code:
'''tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()'''

raises a not implemented error, any workarounds?

Comment: What is your python and tornado versions?

Comment: python 3.8.5 and tornado 6.0.4

Comment: By chance, are you running on Windows?

Comment: Yes windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help if you execute this before getting and starting of your IOLoop `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())`

See https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/index.html?highlight=windows#installation